# Use parent component to pass initial value to child without relying on state ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent Component A that computes some initial value for his child Component B. Actually i compute the initial value in componentDidMount() of Component A and pass it to B through props:

```
<ComponentB initialValue={this.state.value} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

And in component B i do

```
this.state = {value: this.props.initialValue}
```

After this, Component B should manage his state independently. But every time it's value change, i want it to update A's state but with less information.

In Component B:

```
const onChange = (event) => { 
      this.setState({value: event.target.value + "only in B"});
      this.props.handleChange(this.state.value);
}
```

In ComponentA:

```
const handleChange = (value) => { 
      this.setState({value: value});
}
```

The problem is that A always has the last word and value in B doesn't keep the "only in b" suffix. A reset the value of B's state to his internal state value through the initialValue props when it renders again.

So basically, what i want to do is to inherit the initial value from A at first render, and then update A state when a change occurs in B without erasing B's state.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I wanted to say that what you are trying to do goes against the way data naturally flows in React, which is why you are struggling. Generally speaking, the parent component should always hand the most recent and up to date information down to it's children, and also handle the management of that data. If it is data that the parent in no way makes use of and is extremely localized to the child, then the data should never be passed down, it should originate in the child as state.

Comment: As for your question itself, any change in the parent will cause the child to rerender, this will overwrite the child's current state with the props that have now been modified. The only way around this issue is to change your approach in one of the ways I listed above, likely by moving where the data originates at to the child.

Comment: @Reifocs: There's nothing obviously wrong about your code. It might be helpful to post a full example of both the parent and child components to see if there's something else going on. It's possible you're re-mounting the child for some reason, which would reset state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey even though you may do this better way if I understood correctly I think you can achieve what you want by just using:

`this.props.value`

on B Component:

`<input defaultValue={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>`

and then when you handle update just pass in `event.target.value` to parent (A component)

I'm not 100% sure if that's what you are asking but here's example:

https://codepen.io/pegla/pen/qBNxqBd?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Any change in the parent component will trigger a re-render of the child component. I believe the best approach for your situation is after inheriting the initial value from A, set some local state variable to the B component to manage that state specifically so it's separate from A.